# AWS - SQL Server Thesaurus

Tags: amazon-rds, freetext

Is it possible to edit the thesaurus XML file for SQL Server on AWS RDS ?
I tried to find solutions but was unable to come co any conclusion.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The thesaurus is stored in the file system and obviously we do not have access to the filesystem with RDS.